# Texlipse: How do you configure it to show a real time preview?

Tags: latex, eclipse-plugin

I'm running on an Ubuntu and I hope it doesn't matter. Either than the preview it's a great latex editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the [Texlipse man page](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/build.html) mentions *building* and previewing, I do not think it can make a real-time preview, especially when the previewing relies on external tool.

But you could associate that Texlipse editor with other tools able to read the same LaTeX definition file and make a real time preview, like in this question:

[Real-Time LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311118/real-time-latex)

Comment: The PDF reader that comes with TexWorks automatically updates the open PDF if the file changes - and Texclipse automatically builds on save so it's effectively a real time preview (maybe 1sec delay or something)

Comment: @rgvcorley interesting way to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the "Previewing" section on [this manual page](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/build.html).  When I glanced over it though, it didn't look like there is necessarily a way to do a *live* preview.  It is an open source project, so if you really need to scratch that itch there's a way. :)